# Alphabetical sorting of terms (not using a view)

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using the templates to display my terms rather than views but I'd like to change the order that the items are sorted. Currently it appears to be sorted by date. I would like to sort them alphabetically. Is this something I can do in the temeplate.php or within anywhere else?

Comment: How do you call your terms?

Comment: I use a conditional statements within the page template so if term then...

Comment: Do you get back an array that you're rendering or is it already rendered?

Comment: I'm choosing the fields to output yeah from an array

Comment: Can't you just sort the array before rendering it?

Comment: if they come from <?php print render($page['content']); ?> would I be able to do that though?

Comment: hmmm but you need to implement the terms in your content type at some point, how do you do that? give all the code+details you can.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way indeed is using views.

If you really don't like to do so, you could create a custom module, implement hook_menu_alter() to alter the page callback of the taxonomy page:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term'])) {
    $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] => 'MYMODULE_my_taxonomy_page';
  }
}
```

Then write your own version of the taxonomy module's function taxonomy_term_page($term) (using the above example, you would call it MYMODULE_my_taxonomy_page).

Within this function you can alter the call of taxonomy_select_nodes and add a fourth parameter, specifying the desired sort order:

```
$order = array('t.title' => 'ASC')
```

Note that this is working only, if you did not use a field replacement for the title property (e.g. using the title module). Then you would have to write an own version of the taxonomy_select_nodes function as well.

Comment: ok cool giving it a go...

Comment: Let me know, if it worked for you or any information is missing in my answer. Also feel free to upvote/accept the answer once your term page is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Assuming I have done it correctly it just seems to output nothing. I am getting the fields from the node array

Comment: Just checked your comments on your question. I was assuming you were talking of the term page. Seems you asked about the term references on a node page?

Comment: yeah the terms, so on the page template i have a if term then, and then on the node I have a if term then